# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 886: invalid start byte: jsonlines

Tags: python, jsonlines

I am trying to read lines from a jsonl file, but I am getting the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "insertion_script.py", line
> 12, in 
> for line in f.iter():   File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonlines\jsonlines.py",
> line 204, in iter
> skip_empty=skip_empty)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonlines\jsonlines.py",
> line 143, in read
> lineno, line = next(self._line_iter)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
> (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position
> 886: invalid start byte

```
BH_data = []
with jsonlines.open('2401659.jsonl','r') as f:
    for line in f.iter():
        BH_data.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that your data is not actually in UTF-8.  0xA3 happens to be the British pound sterling symbol in the Windows code page.  You should try

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('2401659.jsonl','r',encoding='cp1252') as jfile:
    with jsonlines.Reader(jfile) as f:
```

Comment: I tried that, it gives an error of unexpected argument.

Comment: There's always a way.